# Magento API VBA

Tags: api, access

I am hoping someone can help me. I am trying to write VBA to pull sales data from the Magento api. I am having trouble on the authentication side of things. This is what I have so far.

```
Dim vQuote As String
vQuote = """"

Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String
Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim XMLDOC As New DOMDocument60

sURL = "http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl"

sEnv = "<?xml version=" & vQuote & "1.0" & vQuote & "encoding=" & vQuote & "UTF-8" & vQuote & "?>"
sEnv = sEnv & " <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=" & vQuote & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" & vQuote & " xmlns:ns1=" & vQuote & "urn:Magento"
sEnv = sEnv & "  xmlns:xsd=" & vQuote & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" & vQuote & " xmlns:xsi=" & vQuote & "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
sEnv = sEnv & "                     xmlns:SOAP-ENC=" & vQuote & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
sEnv = sEnv & "                     SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=" & vQuote & "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "      <SOAP-ENV:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "          <ns1:salesOrderList>"
sEnv = sEnv & "              <sessionId xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">abbc417256a3ffb93d130a77a2fd3665</sessionId>"
sEnv = sEnv & "              <filters xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:filters" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                  <filter SOAP-ENC:arrayType=" & vQuote & "ns1:associativeEntity[2]" & vQuote & " xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:associativeArray" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                     <item xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:associativeEntity" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <key xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">status</key>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <value xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">pending</value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                      </item>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                     <item xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:associativeEntity" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <key xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">created_at</key>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <value xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">2011-11-29 15:41:11</value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                      </item>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                  </filter>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                  <complex_filter SOAP-ENC:arrayType=" & vQuote & "ns1:complexFilter[2]" & vQuote & " xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:complexFilterArray" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                      <item xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:complexFilter" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <key xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">order_id</key>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <value xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:associativeEntity" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                              <key xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">in</key>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                              <value xsi:type=" & vQuote & " & vQuote & " & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">Array</value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          </value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                      </item>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                      <item xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:complexFilter" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <key xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">protect_code</key>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          <value xsi:type=" & vQuote & "ns1:associativeEntity" & vQuote & ">"
sEnv = sEnv & "                              <key xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">in</key>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                              <value xsi:type=" & vQuote & "xsd:string" & vQuote & ">a4ffa8</value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                          </value>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                      </item>"
sEnv = sEnv & "                  </complex_filter>"
sEnv = sEnv & "              </filters>"
sEnv = sEnv & "          </ns1:salesOrderList>"
sEnv = sEnv & "      </SOAP-ENV:Body>"
sEnv = sEnv & "  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"


With xmlhtp
.Open "POST", sURL, False

.send sEnv

    XMLDOC.loadXML .responseText
    XMLDOC

    XMLDOC.Save CurrentProject.Path & "\WebQueryResult.xml"

End With
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CData magento Odbc driver, much easier and with cash function so you can pull data on the fly. Be aware Devart also has a driver which I have tried and it is really bad and the support is extremely poor. CData support how ever is excellent.